# Verifying database information using testing jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I currently have the following code it allows me to execute sql queries . My only problem is I want to verify of my query matches a value. Essentially I want my code to do is (1) execute query (which the current code to do. (2) Use the value given by the step one and compare it with an expected value. I just want to verify the database information is correct

```
    public static void  main(String[] args) throws  ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {                                                  
    //Connection URL Syntax: "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:portnumber/db_name"        
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:7708/pmsdb";                   

            String username = "root";   

    //Database Password     
    String password = "root";             

    //Query to Execute      
    String query = "select * from people where id ='10261'";  


    //Load mysql jdbc driver        
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");         

    //Create Connection to DB       
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);

    //Create Statement Object       
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();                  

    // Execute the SQL Query. Store results in ResultSet        
    ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);                         

    // While Loop to iterate through all data and print results     
    while (rs.next()){
        String myName = rs.getString(1);                                        
        String myAge = rs.getString(2);                                                
        System. out.println(myName+"  "+myAge);     
    }       
    // closing DB Connection       
    con.close();   

}
```

}

Comment: I don't see selenium here, and hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: I've update my question

Comment: You want... (1) to execute the database query and (2) compare the retrieved value with the value retrieved from (1)? So you want to compare the returned value with itself? Please clarify your question further.

Comment: What exactly is not working? It is impossible to understand your problem currently.

Comment: Sorry I want to compare it with an expected. Value my query can select a name I just want to find a way to compare the value returned with what I know it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you need to make your program aware of what the expectation actually is; the expected names can be loaded and parsed from an external file (which is the better option, especially if you have a lot of comparisons), or you can use constant Strings or arrays of strings and hard code them (which is the quick and dirty option, suitable for very small tests and prototypes but ugly regardless).

Once you have your expectation loaded, just use .equals comparisons to compare strings.

```
 //Assume Strings expectedname and expectedage are populated with 
 //expectations for this record.
 String myName = rs.getString(1);                                        
 String myAge = rs.getString(2);
 if(!(expectedname.equals(myName) && expectedage.equal(myage)))
     //It didn't match!
 else
     //It matched!
```

Comment: Is there a particular way you would recommend using an external file? I use it for config properties. Never though of using it for data.

Comment: Depends on how you want to store the text file.  Simplest example would be reading in a CSV, be it a home grown implementation with FileReader or leveraging OpenCSV, though JSON or XML are often preferred in more complex situations.